# when to use Gen_Fsm and when to use Gen_Server?

Tags: erlang, gen-server, gen-fsm

After checking out Gen_Fsm and Gen_Server documents, I found that, more or less, they act as similar behavior. In my opinion, if there is one loop function for sending broadcast or listening tcp sock, it is better to use Gen_Fsm, or else to use gen_server. i want to know whether it is right ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have seen right that `gen_server` and `gen_fsm` are very similar in functionality.

However in most programs there is much more `gen_server` than `gen_fsm` usage.

In my opinion `gen_fsm` is only useful when the usage 100% fits the gen_fsm model.  So there has to be a simple and clear finite state machine that fits to your problem.  Be aware that usually FSM's state count tends to explode in the face of the real world.

If you find yourself having lots of secondary state information in `gen_fsm`'s `State`variable its probably time to switch to `gen_server` and add `gen_fsm`' s state to the `State` variable.

Generally when in doubt: use `gen_server`

One disadvantage of both `gen_server` and `gen_fsm` (which comes out worse in `gen_fsm`usually) is that you can't use selective receive.  Selective receive is a important tool for reducing state machine complexity in real world applications.

To have the advantage of both selective receive and OTP behaviours I'd recommend [plain_fsm](https://github.com/uwiger/plain_fsm).

Comment: you said: "... you can't use selective receive.", why is that? I think as long as we don't touch those messages we are not interested in, like `$gen_blah_blah` and system messages, we are fine. If we can control the incoming message's format, we can only receive those we are interested in, like this `receive {some_app_specific_message_tag, Msg} -> ...`

Comment: @NotanID well you will have to implement selective receive yourself in `handle_info`, and won't be able to use `gen_server:call|cast`. At this point, plain_fsm is a better choice.